# jQuery.parseJSON() Invalid Character error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting "Invalid Character Error" when parsing string to JSon but don't know the reason..
please help me out, Here is My code

```
var data = $.parseJSON({ "senderEmail": "Email@gmail.com", "RecieverEmail": "alll", "Message": "j", "DateAndTime": "2013"});
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log("--------------------");

                console.log(data[i].SenderEmail);
                console.log(data[i].RecieverEmail);
                console.log(data[i].DateTime);
                console.log(data[i].Message);

            }
```

Comment: The value you pass to `$.parseJSON` is already an object, not a string containing JSON. Just remove the function call. *"[...] when parsing string to JSon [...]"* I think you are misunderstanding something here. In the context of JavaScript, JSON can only be contained in a string. JSON is a textual representation of data. You can convert arrays and object *to* JSON and convert a string containing JSON to arrays and object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: you already have a JSON object here, `jQuery.parseJSON()` takes a string as input.

Second: to access `data[i]` properties you'll also have to pass a list of objects.

So:

```
var data = $.parseJSON('[{"senderEmail": "Email@gmail.com", "ReceiverEmail": "alll", "Message": "j", "DateAndTime": "2013"}]');

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Now you can access data[i] properties as you want...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

JSON is a string which is a serialized piece of data using a subset of the JS literal syntax.

In your example you are not passing a string to `parseJSON`, you're passing an object literal.

You want:

```
var data = $.parseJSON('{"senderEmail": "Email@gmail.com", "RecieverEmail": "alll", "Message": "j", "DateAndTime": "2013"}');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is already an object (without `quotes`), and not a `json` string, so nothing to parse

```
{
    "senderEmail": "Email@gmail.com",
    "RecieverEmail": "alll",
    "Message": "j",
    "DateAndTime": "2013"
}
```

A json string should be something like this

```
'{ "senderEmail": "Email@gmail.com", "RecieverEmail": "alll", "Message": "j", "DateAndTime": "2013"}'
```

Notice the `quotes` `'{...}'`. This is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/rHkfs/) of looping an object and [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/rHkfs/1/) shows how to loop an object after parsing it from a `json` string, see the difference.

So, if your data is already an object then you don't need to use `$.parseJSON` because it just convert the `json` string to a `JavaScript` object but if this is a `json` string `'{...}'` then parse it (convert the `json` string to an object) then you loop it. `json` means `JavaScript Object Notation` and a `json` string is just a `JavaScript` object inside a string (`'{...}'` and not a real Object) and to make it a real `JavaScript` Object we need to parse it first, unless, we can't use it as an `Object`.

Read more on [json.org](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you trying to parse JSON itself, it is not string

```
var data = $.parseJSON('[{ "senderEmail": "Email@gmail.com", "RecieverEmail": "alll",   "Message": "j", "DateAndTime": "2013"}]');
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log("--------------------");
  console.log(data[i].senderEmail);
  console.log(data[i].RecieverEmail);
  console.log(data[i].Message);
  console.log(data[i].DateAndTime);
};
```